# "No iOS code signing key matches specified provisioning profile" when debuggin on iPhone

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I keep getting this error no matter what I set up in the Apple dev portal.  I download everything through XCode on the Mac.  Restart Visual Studio.  Visual Studio picks up newly downloaded provisioning profile.  I've tried both debug and adHoc provisioning profiles.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I've read other posts and answers, nothing helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your bundle identifier in your app match your app id on the portal? The app id listed on the [portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle) should match (either exactly or with a wildcard *). Then in your info.plist, it should match your CFBundleIdentifier. That's what it uses to match provisioning profiles.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have the info.plist, bundleidentifier, and the app portal all matching now.  Now the error I'm getting is "no signing identities match the specified provisioning profile"

Comment: Did you generate the cert on the machine you're trying to build on? If not, you need to import the public & private keys from the one that generated it. If you can't do that, then you might need to generate a new cert.

Comment: I generated the app id, and provisioning profile in the apple portal.  I have a couple developer certs that were already created from before that work for another app.   I created them in the same Mac I'm building on.  Is the developer certificate what you are talking about?

Comment: I solved the issue.  I was using a provisioning profile with a revoked certificate somehow

Answer (score 3):

I encountered same issue. I was fixed it by deleting previous/existing created certificate and provisioning profile(developer.apple.com) and created and installed every certificate and provisioning profile from scratch.

First created new certificate ,installed it on keychain Access after creating iOS_distribution.cer file and then create provisioning profile on portal(developer.apple.com) and download installed it.

It fixed my issue - 
**No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile 'VS: WildCard Development'.
Done building target "_DetectSigningIdentity" in project "XXXX." -- FAILED**.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by deleting previous created certificate too. I reinstalled macOS, so maybe that is the cause. I have been subscribing to Apple Development Program though (so I can use Auto Provision Profile).

Answer (score 1):

For me the fix was to go into project --> properties --> iOS Bundle Signing, and choose "manual provisioning".  For some reason "automatic provisioning" wasn't working for the debug build *(it does work for release though, at least in VS 17.3 Preview 3, which fixes that feature)*

Answer (score 0):

For me I wasn't signed into my developer account in XCode.
Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts...

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved this problem, using Visual Studio 2022.

1. iOS Project -> Properties -> iOS Bundle Signing
2. Set Team to 'Empty' / Blank to clear the combo box.
3. Save & Close Visual Studio. Reopen Visual Studio & your project.
4. Connect to MAC Host
5. again in iOS Bundle Signing, Select your team.
6. Save, Rebuild and Deploy.

Seems that Visual Studio is just pretending to re-download the provisioning profiles from the MAC Host, the restart seems to trigger it into working again.