# Issue with Apple Porvisioning and Visual Studio

Tags: ios, xamarin, apple-developer

I am having an issue with my apple developer account. I have a profile created which is the following.

[image]

But when I run in visual studio and xamrian ios project I AM Getting the following error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile 'VS: WildCard Development'.  Project.iOS

As Far as I was aware the wildcard profile should allow me to develop all apps automatically however I am on a personal account I am at present putting in a request for apple to change it to a business account.

Comment: Are you using automatic provisioning or manual provisioning?  Have a look at these threads may help: [No iOS signing identities match the specified provisioning profile](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/266713/#Comment_266713) and [specified provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297371/no-ios-code-signing-key-matches-specified-provisioning-profile-when-debuggin-o).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT that was the issue but its still not deploying to the iPhone apparently their an issue stopping it will be fixed in new version theirs an issue with 13.3